# Prevent folder deletion in document library - Explorer view snafu

Tags: 2010, document-library, event-handlers, explorer-view, ssom

We want to prevent users from deleting top level folders in a document library. We created an event receiver on ItemDeleting that checks if the item type is a folder and if the path is the top level, if so it cancels the event.

```
public override void ItemDeleting(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    //Boilerplate code and other logic not shown
    ....
    errorMsg = "Delete of top level folders is not allowed.";
    properties.ErrorMessage = errorMsg;
    properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError; 
    properties.RedirectUrl = "/_layouts/OurCompany/CustomError.aspx?edrmsMsg=" + errorMsg;
}
```

This works fine from the GUI however it appears it doesn't work so well from Explorer view. When a user tries to delete a top level folder from Explorer view the event receiver cancels the folder deletion but still allows SharePoint to delete all items inside the folder. We are guessing that SharePoint is not transactional in its deletion of child / nested items.

Is there any way to fix the event receiver to block the deletion of child / nested items, or is there another way to implement our business requirement?

Comment: Does event receiver fires when you delete any items separately using Explorer view?

Comment: Yes the ItemDeleting event receiver does fire both when items and folders are deleted via Explorer view

Comment: @JohnC did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: No, we didn't pursue it further, we abandoned this approach. If you follow the links in @suren's answer there is a suggestion to use workflow. If someone reports that this works I will accept that answer.

Comment: How annoying. I have the same problem where in Explorer view the event fires but cancelling the event does not work. The workflow approach suggested in the link is far from ideal, but perhaps the only way to get around this issue. Thanks.

Comment: SharePoint has these awful gaping holes that make it a real pain as a platform for building custom solutions; in many/most cases you are better off avoiding code-based customizations,

Answer (score -1):

I think event receiver will not fire when do any action in Explorer view. Please refer the following links for workaround.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370201/when-does-sharepoint-list-itemdeleting-event-actually-fire

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486448/sharepoint-list-event-receivers-not-firing-when-copying-and-pasting-using-explor

Comment: Not correct, item events do fire for actions in Explorer view, at least for SP 2010 SP2.