# Feature Stapler on Document Library to Set New Folder Off

Tags: document-library, feature-stapling

I would like to have the 'New Folder' option turned off be Default.  Are there examples of maybe creating a Feature stapler to do this?

Comment: check this AND LET US KNOW IF IT WORKS FOR YOU.http://jassimkhan.blogspot.com/2010/10/sharepoint-2010-disable-new-folder.html

Comment: Not exaclt, that removes the Action item from the Ribbon.  I want to set the default setting to "no".  Something like Dim targetList As SPList = properties.List and then targetList.EnableFolderCreation = FALSE

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is how I did it.  I wanted the Folder Settings in the Library Settings to default to "No" instead of the OOB setting of "Yes".

Steps:
1. Created an Event Receiver to set the NoCrawl to "True"
2. Create an Empty Element with a Feature Scoped to Site.

Event Receiver:

```
    Imports Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities
    Imports Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow
    Imports Microsoft.Office.Server

    Public Class DocumentLibraryProvisioning 
        Inherits SPListEventReceiver

        ''' <summary>
        ''' A list was added.
        ''' </summary>
        Public Overrides Sub ListAdded(properties As SPListEventProperties)
            MyBase.ListAdded(properties)

            'Get the List that has been Added
            Dim targetList As SPList = properties.List

            Try
                'Set Make "New Folder" command available? to "No"
                targetList.EnableFolderCreation = False
                targetList.NoCrawl = True
                targetList.Update()
            Catch ex As Exception
                'Throw a message in the ULS Logging
                Microsoft.Office.Server.Diagnostics.PortalLog.LogString("Exception Occurred Carmeuse.SP.ER.DefaultNoFolders: {0} || {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace)
            End Try

        End Sub

    End Class
```

Elements.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  !-- Team Site -->
  FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation Id="29D85C25-170C-4df9-A641-12DB0B9D4130" TemplateName="STS#0"></FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation>
/Elements>
```

Regards,
Bismarck

Answer (score -1):

You can disable it from the advanced setting of the list.
[image]

Or if via CSS you can simply hide the button:

```
#Ribbon\.Documents\.New\.NewFolder-Large
{
    display:none;
}
```

But the best solution would be to create an event receiver which denies any attempt to add a new folder based on your own logic.

Take a look to this old question: [Prevent folder creation](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/86147/prevent-folder-creation)

Comment: why not useful answer?

Comment: I need to have this Folder setting set to "no" by default in the Library Settings. OOB it is set to Yes.

Comment: @Bismarck I saw your answer, EnableFolderCreation  plus event receiver is the best solution. Btw add comments before to downvote without reason. Enjoy!